# telnet with ansible to cisco switch isn't working

Tags: ansible, telnet, cisco

I have a cisco switches in my lab, since they initially have telnet connection configured I want to use it for initial configuration with ansible (SSH access, hostname, domain ... etc).

I'm trying to use this module:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/netcommon/telnet_module.html#parameters

This is my current playbook but it's not working as expected:

```
- name: Initial access with Telnet
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: wired
  tasks:
  - name: set SSH with telnet connection # Configure SSH access to the netowrk devices
    ansible.netcommon.telnet:
      port: 14038
      password: "mainpass"
      send_newline: yes
      prompts:
      - '[>]'
      commands:
      - enable
```

When I run this playbook I don't get anything on the CLI and it stays that way until I terminate it:

```
sumaia@main-srv:~/ansible$ ansible-playbook init.yaml

PLAY [Initial access with Telnet] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set SSH with telnet connection] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
sumaia@main-srv:~/ansible$
```

I verified telnet access with putty and it works:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
To log in to this device, use the following password/credentials:

enable password mainpass
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


9300>en
Password:
9300#
```

When I start the telnet session, I need to press enter then enable to enter the password, not sure how will this reflect in the playbook.

Comment: The single prompt you set is not aligned in any way with the one you get after logging in manually. Try with `prompts: ['#']`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that the switch is waiting for carriage return before displaying the MOTD banner so it never sends the prompt that ansible is looking for, the only way I found around this was to add a send_carriage_return parameter to a forked version of the ansible.netcommon.telnet module.